# How do I open a `.mhtml` file in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios6

Is there any library available for this? If not, is there a way to convert this .mhtml file into .html to open in iOS directly in UIWebView?

Comment: did you try to just open it?

Comment: i don't know how to open this so pls help me how to open

Comment: Is it a coincidence that almost the [exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277387/can-i-open-the-mht-or-mhtml-file-in-uiwebview-of-ios) was asked at almost the exact same time?

Comment: I mean, did you try to just open it as a .html?

Comment: Yes sir i have triend but not open

Comment: @JatiendarKumar: Were you able to open the .mht file in webview?

Comment: @UmeshKumar yes i am open but firstly converted .mhtml file into html on .net parser in backend then show on uiwebview

Comment: @JatiendarKumar: Do you have any sample code for the conversion of .mhtml to html?