# Can i Open .mht or .mhtml file in Uiwebview of Ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, ios7.1

Is there any criteria to convert .mht file to .html So i can open it in iosWebview.
And Can i open the .mht file in ios webview?
Is there any library or third party tool available to perform the same?

Comment: did you try to open it?

Comment: Ya i tried, but i am not able to open it.

Comment: I have been trying to do the same. Any solution bro?

Comment: Paid library available for .mhtml file http://www.chilkatsoft.com/mht-objc.asp <= go through it.

Comment: @Tirth: Have you used this library before? I used it but I couldn't find my output file in the directory that I specified. Dont know whether the conversion of .mht->.html happens and if it does, can't find the file in the directory specified.

Comment: @RohitMehta: Were you able to open the .mht file in webview?